# Flutter Audioplayers ByteSource is not supported on ios

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to implement amazon polly in my flutter project but I am unable to run it on iOS devices. It works perfectly fine on android. I am using a Byte source which is not supported on iOS.

```
BytesSource source = BytesSource(bytes);
await audioPlayer.play(source);
```

In the documentation it is written:

```
/// Source containing the actual bytes of the media to be played.
///
/// This is currently only supported for Android (SDK >= 23).
```

So my question is How do I play bytes in iOS or macOS devices with audioplayers package? Do I need to use another package or is a workaround available?

Answer (score 2):

The only way that is currently available outside of Android is to write those bytes to a file and then use that file in AudioPlayers with `DeviceFileSource`.

You can follow this issue to get notified about when `BytesSource` is implemented for other platforms:
https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1269